# Thymeleaf 3.1 fails to render base64 image - TemplateProcessingException

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am migrating my application to Spring boot 3.0.1, and the thymeleaf version from 2 to 3.1

I have this line of code:

```
<img class="img-logo-main" src="#" alt="logo" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${logoMBase64}}" width="335" height="82">
```

which was executing normally before the upgrade, but now I am getting:

```
TemplateProcessingException - Caused by: 

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No configured link builder instance was able to build link with base "data:image/jpeg;base64,null" and parameters null (template: "my-template.html" - line 3, col 51)
```

NOTES: I am sending the `logoMBase64` param. IDK why the log states null

Am I missing any configuration? Or have there been any changes in support for rendering base64 imgs?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue...  <img th:src="@{'data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,' + ${qrCode}}"/>

Comment: I have fixed it this way:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057838/migration-from-thymeleaf-3-0-to-3-1