# Migration from thymeleaf 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: spring, kotlin, thymeleaf

I have a minimalistic thymeleaf config in my spring boot app, which is used just to render the html into PDF file.

I am upgrading to spring boot 3, and need to upgrade **thymeleaf** from 3.0 to 3.1

Here is my old code before upgrade to spring boot 3, the main difference is the construction of `WebContext`. In **thymeleaf 3.0** I was building it based on servlet request/response, but in **thymeleaf 3.1**, we are building it from WebExchange object

**Controller for Thymeleaf 3.0**

```
override fun previewDataController(
    request: HttpServletRequest,
    response: HttpServletResponse,
    objId: UUID,
): ResponseEntity<ByteArray> {
    val context = WebContext(request, response, request.servletContext)
    val pdfData = someService.previewData(context, objId)
    ...
}
```

And the upgrade to **Thymeleaf 3.1**

```
override fun previewDataController(
    webExchange: IWebExchange,
    objId: UUID,
): ResponseEntity<ByteArray> {
    val context = WebContext(webExchange, webExchange.locale)
    val pdfData = someService.previewData(context, objId)
    ...
}
```

Here is the failing code

```
@Autowired
val templateEngine: TemplateEngine

...

fun someMethod(context: WebContext) {
    val htmlString = templateEngine.process("resources/template", context)
    ...
}
```

I have the object `object` in the context, and I can see in debug that this property is not null

Here is the template:

```
<body>
    <p>Name <span th:text="${object.name}">#</span></p>
</body>
```

But my unit test is failing, stating that `object` from the template is null. Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this the correct way to build the **IWebExchange** object? Will it be bound by spring?
2. Am I missing any configuration for the new 3.1 version?
3. Can it be a problem of the test context config?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you change your controller? `IWebExchange` is not something that spring understands, you should create an instance yourself using the request and response. Also wy are you working with `Thymeleaf` directly instead of returning the name of the view to render and let Spring handle all the complexity. Also `resources/template` doesn't seem right, as that looks to me you are pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was the intended design, which is working fine (regarding the return of the view and the view location). How should I build the IWebExchange object from servletRequest and servletResponse? I was looking for existing implementations, but could not find a right constructor

Comment: Assuming you are using an embedded container and thus use Jakarta use `JakartaServletWebApplication.buildExchange(request, response);` which you can then use to create the `WebContext`. You should be able to inject the application into your class (you should be able to construct one in the applicationcontext as it requires a `ServletContext`).

Comment: I am getting this error: Cannot build an application for a request which servlet context does not match with the application that it is being built for.

Comment: how should I configure the JakartaServletWebApplication in spring boot?

Comment: YOu can also create it in the method using `request.getServletContext()` instead of injecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things have changed considerably for Thymeleaf. Mostly because the `JavaEE` and `JakartaEE` support it provides, so things needed to be abstracted away. Simply creating a `WebExchange` is a bit more involved now.

What you should be able to do (Java code which you can probably convert).

```java
public class ThymeleafHelper {

  public static WebContext createContext(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    var application = JakartaServletWebApplication.buildApplication(req.getServletContext());
    var exchange application.buildExchange(req, res);
    return new WebContext(exchange);
  }
}
```

You should be able to call this (and convert it to Kotlin) to create the `WebContext` you will need.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems that it fixed the problem. I will run the tests now, but the app didn't crash